# How can i call my method after create new object in odoo 10?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

I'm using odoo 10 i inherited from module stock.quant i add a new attribute and a new method.
i want my method execute after each creating a new object in stock.quant.
This is my code 
Thanks for help

```
class stock_quant(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'stock.quant'
    inventory_value_charge = fields.Float('Total Value',store=True,compute='update_stock_value')

    @api.one
    @api.depends('qty')
    def update_stock_value(self):
        stock_price_obj = self.env['stock.price.partition'].search([('id', '!=', False)])
        val_obj = stock_price_obj.search([('reception.pack_operation_product_ids.pack_lot_ids.lot_id.id', '=', self.lot_id.id)])
        if val_obj!= False:
            val_obj.calccule_price()
        else:
            self.inventory_value_charge=self.inventory_value
        #stock_price_obj = self.env['stock.price.partition'].search([('reception.pack_operation_product_ids.pack_lot_ids.lot_id.id', '=', self.lot_id.id)])
        return True

    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        res = super(stock_quant, self).create(vals)
        self.update_stock_value()
        return res
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change your create function like this

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    res = super(stock_quant, self).create(vals)
    res.update_stock_value()
    return res
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all the field is computed you don't have to call
the method because it's allready called in the process of
create call. and in write call too but only if you change the qty field.

So remove the create method you are just calling it for the second time.

Now make sure that your method is called by adding some print calls if 
you don't know how to use debug in you IDE.

Make sure you import the module in your `__init__` files.